# convert JSP EL byte[] to image?

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl, el

I have a jsp page like below:

```
<c:forEach var="employeeVO" items="${list}">

    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${employeeVO.employee_pic}" alt="Card image cap"/>
    <h5>${employeeVO.employee_position}</h5>
    <p>${employeeVO.employee_salary}</p>

</c:forEach>
```

where ${employeeVO.employee_position} and ${employeeVO.employee_salary} work just fine as they are both String type
my question is ${employeeVO.employee_pic} this would return byte[] which I don't know how to covert it as a legit source?
when I check the page source code it shows like this:
src="data:image/jpeg;base64,[B@59e9139b"
if more information needed please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: What does `${employeeVO.employee_pic}` represent? The full path to the image file?

Comment: it's the full data (byte[] type) which I get from database

Comment: So you don't have the actual file saved in a folder anywhere on your system, you just have the bytecode saved in a database table somewhere?

Comment: yes, so here <c:forEach var="employeeVO" items="${list}"> I have a list stores  javaBean(employeeVO) and I extract employee_pic, employee_position, employee_salary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't simply represent byte[] in html.

You can are represent the file data as a base64 format as your html is written. The problem is that you are not sending a base64 string, but the byte [].

You need to expose the data the way it will be read. That is, it is necessary to represent it as a base64 string.

For this, you can create a getter in employeeVO that returns the representation of the file in a base64 string. As an example

```
public String getEmployee_picAsBase64 (){
    ... do logic to convert file in a base64 string and return it.
}
```

then, you can write this in html:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${employeeVO.employee_picAsBase64}" alt="Card image cap"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out in the end and the solution is exactly as your answer!